# How do I specify a return type of my derived object in MustOverride function?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, inheritance

I am wanting to create a MustOverride Function in a MustInherit Class that would have a return type of the derived class.  I'll try to illustrate below...

```
Public MustInherit Class ModelBase
   Public MustOverride Function FindByUniqueAttributes() As _______
End Class

Public Class Person
   Inherits ModelBase

   Public Overrides Shared Function FindByUniqueAttributes() As _______
       ' ...
   End Function
End Class
```

With the setup above how should I go about filling in the blanks I've provided for the return types?  I want the derived class to contain it's own type as the return type.

**Update**

```
Public Overrides Function SaveChanges() As Integer
    For Each e In Me.ChangeTracker.Entries
        If e.State = EntityState.Added Then
            Dim mb = DirectCast(e.Entity, ModelBase) ' Erroring out after changes

            mb.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now
            mb.UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now
        End If
        If e.State = EntityState.Modified Then
            Dim mb = DirectCast(e.Entity, ModelBase) ' Erroring out after changes

            mb.UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now
        End If
    Next

    Return MyBase.SaveChanges()

End Function
```

Comment: A `Shared` member can never be `Overridable`.

Comment: Whoops thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment:

> *"A Shared member can never be Overridable."*

With that being said you might want to use a generic type in your `ModelBase`. Something like this:

```
Public MustInherit Class ModelBase

    Public Shared Function FindByUniqueAttributes(Of TEntity)() As TEntity
    End Function

End Class
```

Or this:

```
Public MustInherit Class ModelBase(Of TEntity)

    Public MustOverride Function FindByUniqueAttributes() As TEntity

End Class

Public Class Person
    Inherits ModelBase(Of Person)

    Public Overrides Function FindByUniqueAttributes() As Person
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: @moopasta Great! Also, you might want to add some constraints to `TEntity`. This is how I tend to do it: `ModelBase(Of TEntity As {Class, New})`

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful didn't know about that at all until just pulling up the documentation on Type Parameter constraints.

Comment: Bjorn, I had Overridden the SaveChanges function in my ModelBase and had a line in it `Dim mb = DirectCast(e.Entity, ModelBase)` which is no longer valid. I'll add the relevant code to the original question.  If possible, could you point out how I need to alter it so I can provide the Type to cast to I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: @moopasta Have you tried `Dim mb = DirectCast(e.Entity, Person)` or `Dim mb = DirectCast(e.Entity, ModelBase(Of Person))`?

Comment: Bjorn, Well I didn't want to have to replicate that code for every model that I inherit from ModelBase. I was looking to try and do something like `ModelBase(Of TEntity)` or if I do ModelBase(Of Person) I suppose that would work as long as I only altered attributes that are apart of ModelBase?

Comment: @moopasta If the `SaveChanges` is overridden in `Person` then you'll have to cast as shown in my previous comment. If it's overridden in `ModelBase` then cast to `ModelBase(Of TEntity)`.